# prefix url to output from json jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, yq

Team,
I have output and I want to prefix it with a url.

```
kubectl get nodes -l nodeGroup=gpu -o wide --no-headers -o json | jq '.items[] | .metadata.name, .metadata.labels."team.com/cordon-reason"' | awk '{print $1}' | paste - -
```

output

```
"node1" "testing"
"node2" null
```

expected output

```
"node1" "https://jira.test.com/testing"
"node2" "https://jira.test.com/null"
```

Comment: Why use `awk` at all, instead of ask `jq` to directly generate the output you want?

Comment: BTW, could you provide sample `kubectl get nodes` output so those of us who don't have Kubernetes clusters handy can still test our answers?

Comment: yeah: i just used what ever i could to get to my need. you may suggest better answer. also any idea why is my question marked for close? and i can't list my sample output coz SO keeps complaining `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

Comment: The single close vote (of three needed for anything to actually happen) is under the category "need details or clarity". I can't speak for the person who cast it definitively, but I'd assume they're also seeing the question as inadequate without providing data necessary before answers can be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you want:

```
jq -r '.items[] | [.metadata.name, "https://jira.test.com/\(.metadata.labels["test.com/cordon-reason"])"] | @tsv'
```

Comment: kind puzzled. where is your single quote ending? `'`

Comment: That's a copy/paste error, missed the last character. That said, because you didn't provide input, this is necessarily untested.

Answer (score 0):

aah: just figured out but is this the right way?

```
-o json | jq '.items[] | .metadata.name, .metadata.labels."test.com/cordon-reason"' | awk '{print $1}' | paste - - | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 https://jira.test.com/$2' --
```

output

```
node1 https://jira.test.com/testing
node2 https://jira.test.com/null
```

Comment: If you don't show what you're actually processing, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: i can't list my sample output coz SO keeps complaining ` It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. ` any other way to upload my sample output. its 30280 chars?

Comment: Cut it down to the shortest input that will generate the same output. There's certainly plenty of unrelated content in that 30,000 characters that can be removed without breaking the rest of your pipeline.

Comment: Or if that's not feasible, upload it to https://gist.github.com/ or similar and have the code in the question `curl` the raw copy to use as input. We do ask that questions be complete enough to answer, test, and understand (both the question and its answers) even if all links break, but as long as there's sufficient explanation of the data format absent that link, I don't see this one getting closed over it.

Comment: BTW, the question says your desired output has literal double-quotes in it, but the sample output you give here doesn't. Which reflects what you actually want?

Comment: Okay: let me upload to github shortly. Coz trimming is too much work for 30k chars and I don’t even know when will SO like it.